# Exception occurs while opening .xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: android, file, exception, apache-poi

I have been working on an android application in which i have to open .xls and .xlsx file for further implementation. In case of .xls everything is working fine but when i try to open .xls x file it gives me exception.  below is my code
Please help me solving these exception

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_code  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();

            String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            if(FilePath.endsWith(".xlsx")){
try{
                    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath));
                    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                    XSSFSheet mySheet2 = myWorkBook2.getSheetAt(0);}
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 


                }
```

jars which iam using:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.13.jar
- poi-3.9-20121203.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Logcat error

```
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] dat=file:///sdcard/test .xlsx flg=0x3000000 cmp=miyowa.android.microsoft.wlm/com.miyowa.android.framework.ui.miyowaExplorer.MiyowaExplorer (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.converter/com.example.converter.Homepage}: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3142)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3185)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774): Caused by: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:207)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at com.example.converter.Homepage.onActivityResult(Homepage.java:358)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4694)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3138)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     ... 11 more
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     ... 17 more
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:44)
07-05 14:09:31.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6774):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSpreadsheet](http://www.independentsoft.com/jspreadsheet) is another API for Java and Android. It reads and creates .xlsx file. There are no dependencies, only one jar file.

Comment: This library is NOT FREE

Answer (score 4):

See the [Apache POI Components and Dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) - you are missing the `poi-ooxml-schemas` file which is why you're getting a class not found exception for the schemas classes

Comment: i added poi-ooxml-schemas but now iam getting Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2 and my application does not runs..what should i do now??

Comment: Ask a fresh question, as you're onto a different problem now!

Comment: ok can you tell me if any  Api other than Apache POI can used to read .xlsx file ??

Comment: POI will read .xlsx files just fine. We have now solved this problem (missing jar), if you are having more problems you need to ask a *new* question for those