# How to fill in Excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jsoup

I have the following code to fill in the Excel file,
with information that I get from the Internet using Jsoup.

```
package knvbj;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class KNVBJ {

private static int Clnummer=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/muratcanpinar/Downloads/KNVBJ/build/classes/knvbj/ClubInformation.xlsx");
        List<String> urlList = ReadXlsx.readXlsx();
        urlList.get(1);
        for (String url : urlList) {
            System.out.println("url: " + url);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlList.get(i))
                    .data("query", "Java")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .post();

            Element content1 = doc.getElementsByClass("details").first();
            String body = content1.toString();
            Document docb = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
            Element bbd = docb.body();
            String kkj = bbd.toString();                

            Document finalDocument = Jsoup.parse(kkj);
            Element ClubName = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("title").first();
            String NameOfClub = ClubName.text();
            System.out.println(NameOfClub);    

            Element Adres = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("text").get(1);

            String[] addressParts = Adres.html().split("<br />");
            String SplitString;
            String PlaatsName;
            String Straat;
            String telNo;
            String Accommodatie;
            String Postcode;                

            Accommodatie = addressParts[0].trim();
            Straat = addressParts[1].trim();
            SplitString = addressParts[2].trim();
            telNo = addressParts[3].trim();

            String splitted[]= SplitString.split(" ");
            Postcode = splitted[0];
            PlaatsName = splitted[1];

            System.out.println(Accommodatie + " " + Straat + " " + " postcode " + Postcode + " Plaatsname " + PlaatsName+ " "+ telNo);

            Elements anchors = finalDocument.getElementsByTag("a");
            String email = anchors.get(1).text();    

            String fname = "/Users/muratcanpinar/Downloads/KNVBJ/src/knvbj/Voetbalclubs.xlsx";
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname);                       

            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);

            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row r1 = sheet.getRow(0);

            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(NameOfClub);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Accommodatie);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Straat);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Postcode);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(PlaatsName);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(telNo);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(email);

            wb.write(out);               
        }
  out.close();
    }           
}
```

With this above code i can just fill one row, en then a get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@f46fdc1
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:479)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1414)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:179)
    at knvbj.KNVBJ.main(KNVBJ.java:101)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@f46fdc1
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:470)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing four? Thanks a lot.

Comment: at knvbj.KNVBJ.main(KNVBJ.java:101 -- could you point out this line

Comment: That is this line wb.write(out); what is wrong with that ? Do you have some suggestions to solve this problem  ? Thank you

Comment: Apache POI "only" supports Excel 2007 file format. Is `Voetbalclubs.xlsx` Excel 2007 ?

Comment: No this is excel 2010, How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Save `Voetbalclubs.xlsx` in format 2007 from Excel (aka `.xls`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485309/exception-occurs-while-opening-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi/17550202#17550202

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this?  I am getting the same error:  `org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller`

Comment: @PeterMmm Microsoft introduced the .xlsx format in Excel 2007. The prior format .xls was the default in Excel 2003 and prior.

Comment: @DavidWilliams can you provide a bit more logging? (See my answer on how to get it)

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in your `FileOutputStream` variable `out` being used more than once for the same `Workbook`. Opening and closing the `FileOutputStream` `out` within the loop fix your exception. POI, and/or the xml/zip library, don't like to use the same stream more than once.

If you use the same code you had with 1 loop, it works, with 2, it will crashes with the exception you have.

Here's a quick fix with a simple code to replace what the JSoup code did :

```
  private static int Clnummer = 1;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("yourfilePath");
      String NameOfClub = "Potaoes club";
      System.out.println(NameOfClub);

      String PlaatsName;
      String Straat;
      String telNo;
      String Accommodatie;
      String Postcode;

      Accommodatie = "123";
      Straat = "Potatoes club street";
      telNo = "123456789";

      Postcode = "P0P0P0";
      PlaatsName = "PotatoCity";

      String email = "potatoKing@potato.com";

      String fname = "guessing this is a template file";
      InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname);                       

      Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);

      Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
      Row r1 = sheet.getRow(0);

      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(NameOfClub);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Accommodatie);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Straat);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Postcode);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(PlaatsName);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(telNo);
      r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(email);

      wb.write(out);
      out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the current code, you are trying to write the `ClubInformation.xlsx` into one sheet of `Voetbalclubs.xlsx` . Thus it is giving an error. (xlsx is a xml format, thus you get error while writing `/docProps/app.xml`).

I have modified your code as below. Change the line  `List<String> urlList = Arrays.asList("http://google.com");` as per your need.
Let me know if this works

```
public class KNVBJ {

private static int Clnummer=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ClubInformation.xlsx");
        List<String> urlList = Arrays.asList("http://google.com");
        urlList.get(0);
        for (String url : urlList) {
            System.out.println("url: " + url);
        }
        String fname = "Voetbalclubs.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fname); 
        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlList.get(i))
                    .data("query", "Java")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .post();

            Element content1 = doc.getElementsByClass("details").first();
            String body = content1.toString();
            Document docb = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
            Element bbd = docb.body();
            String kkj = bbd.toString();                

            Document finalDocument = Jsoup.parse(kkj);
            Element ClubName = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("title").first();
            String NameOfClub = ClubName.text();
            System.out.println(NameOfClub);    

            Element Adres = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("text").get(1);

            String[] addressParts = Adres.html().split("<br />");
            String SplitString;
            String PlaatsName;
            String Straat;
            String telNo;
            String Accommodatie;
            String Postcode;                

            Accommodatie = addressParts[0].trim();
            Straat = addressParts[1].trim();
            SplitString = addressParts[2].trim();
            telNo = addressParts[3].trim();

            String splitted[]= SplitString.split(" ");
            Postcode = splitted[0];
            PlaatsName = splitted[1];

            System.out.println(Accommodatie + " " + Straat + " " + " postcode " + Postcode + " Plaatsname " + PlaatsName+ " "+ telNo);

            org.jsoup.select.Elements anchors = finalDocument.getElementsByTag("a");
            String email = anchors.get(1).text();    

                   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row r1 = sheet.getRow(0);

            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(NameOfClub);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Accommodatie);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Straat);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Postcode);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(PlaatsName);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(telNo);
            r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(email);

            wb.write(output);        

        }
  out.close();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Let me know if there are any questions on this?

Comment: The `FileOutputStream` variable `out` is not used in your answer. I don't think writing one `xlsx` file in another cause this problem, he's not writing to a sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Make a test program of the last 13 lines using fixed sane values. If this fails as well the problem is most likely the Input Template. If this works the problem are the values you get from Soup. Print them so see if there are any strange values.

Posting only the smaller 13 lines program will also increase the chance of getting answers. And of course you can try to use another Voetbalclubs.xlsx file for fun, too.

Comment: No, this happens with perfectly sane values.  In my case it is inconsistent across environments too, works locally, throws this error in production.

Comment: same input file? same java version?

Comment: the file is generated dynamically from a query and is not large, 10 rows x 10 columns x 2 tabs.  let me ask about the java version

Comment: The file Voetbalclubs.xlsx is created dynamically? Did you used one of the created files in your local environment? (NB: not talking about ClubInformation.xlsx)

Comment: Hi David, I have the same issue with dinamically created file. Works locally but not on server. Did you managed to solve this? (The issue is present only when using xlsx, working fine with xls). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First: It's better to start with a working example and work your way from there. So start with the sample code that writes a simple string to a single cell a new sheet, then write to an existing sheet on a local filesystem, and only then write data you've parsed from the web. This way, when you run into problems, you've a better idea where to look for a solution.

The exception you're listing is the generic exception that gets thrown by [ZipPackage](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/ZipPackage.java/) when saving fails:

```
if (!defaultPartMarshaller.marshall(part, zos))
    throw new OpenXML4JException("The part " + part.getPartName().getURI()
    + " fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller " + defaultPartMarshaller);
```

So the `marshall` method on the defaultPartMarshaller returns false and the internal exception which is the cause of the failure is lost.
The DefaultMarshaller does not do much, it simply asks the part to save itself to the OutputStream.

From there it gets a little less certain what kind of PackagePart is being saved. But for instance the [ZipPartMarshaller](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/internal/marshallers/ZipPartMarshaller.java#ZipPartMarshaller) catches any exceptions that occur and logs them before returning false:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    logger.log(POILogger.ERROR,"Cannot write: " + part.getPartName() + ": in ZIP",
        ioe);
    return false;
}
```

So could you take a look at the rest of the output, see if any more relevant info gets logged before this exception?

If you cannot find more relevant logging, this is quite normal cause by default, the logger is a NullLogger which doesn't log a thing. Could you set the runtime property `org.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger` (for example by starting java with command line argument `-Dorg.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger`) and see if this produces more logging?

Comment: Giving bounty debugging info.  Still think my issue was a timeout and a closed output stream by amazon.

Answer (score 1):

For me this appears to have been caused by a timeout in AWS, closing the output stream.  the error message is not helpful and misleading.  That's the best I could come up with so far from available info.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when the file used to create the output stream already had data. If you are looking to **append** data to the file, you must indicate so in the file output stream object:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/muratcanpinar/Downloads/KNVBJ/build/classes/knvbj/ClubInformation.xlsx", true);
```

When you do this, `wb.write(out)` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
package knvbj;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class KNVBJ {

private static int Clnummer=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {       
        List<String> urlList = ReadXlsx.readXlsx();
        urlList.get(1);
        for (String url : urlList) {
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlList.get(i))
                .data("query", "Java")
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .cookie("auth", "token")
                .timeout(3000)
                .post();

        Element content1 = doc.getElementsByClass("details").first();
        String body = content1.toString();
        Document docb = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
        Element bbd = docb.body();
        String kkj = bbd.toString();                

        Document finalDocument = Jsoup.parse(kkj);
        Element ClubName = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("title").first();
        String NameOfClub = ClubName.text();
        System.out.println(NameOfClub);    

        Element Adres = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("text").get(1);

        String[] addressParts = Adres.html().split("<br />");
        String SplitString;
        String PlaatsName;
        String Straat;
        String telNo;
        String Accommodatie;
        String Postcode;                

        Accommodatie = addressParts[0].trim();
        Straat = addressParts[1].trim();
        SplitString = addressParts[2].trim();
        telNo = addressParts[3].trim();

        String splitted[]= SplitString.split(" ");
        Postcode = splitted[0];
        PlaatsName = splitted[1];

        System.out.println(Accommodatie + " " + Straat + " " + " postcode " + Postcode + " Plaatsname " + PlaatsName+ " "+ telNo);

        Elements anchors = finalDocument.getElementsByTag("a");
        String email = anchors.get(1).text();    

        String fname = "/Users/muratcanpinar/Downloads/KNVBJ/src/knvbj/Voetbalclubs.xlsx";
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname);                       

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row r1 = sheet.getRow(0);

        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(NameOfClub);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Accommodatie);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Straat);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(Postcode);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(PlaatsName);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(telNo);
        r1.createCell(Clnummer++).setCellValue(email);                          
    }
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/muratcanpinar/Downloads/KNVBJ/build/classes/knvbj/ClubI nformation.xlsx",true);
wb.write(out); 
out.close();
    }           
}
```

you need to create output Stream after you created all cells,then write them to the file. see the codes in details.

Answer (score -1):

Write below sentence outside for loop

wb.write(out);

Comment: While this might address the OP's issue, can you add a couple of sentences to explain why this helps.