# Unable to open excel file. Throws "Unreadable format" error

Tags: java, string, excel, apache-poi

I am actually trying to copy a `String[]`into excel. Code is something like this.

```
    int ExRows = 2, ExCols = 2;
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet xs = wb.createSheet("Sheet");
    try {
            String[] inputArr = {"Gender", "Age", "Male", "45"};              
            int val =0;
            for(int i =0;i<ExRows;i++){
                XSSFRow row = xs.createRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<ExCols;j++){
                    FileOutputStream DestFile = new FileOutputStream("H:\\Docs\\DestExcelRecord\\DestMedicalRecord.xls");
                    String str = inputArr[val];                        
                    row.createCell(j).setCellValue(str);                        
                    wb.write(DestFile);
                    val= val+1;
                    DestFile.close();
                }                   
            }
        }
```

[When I try opening the file, this is the first error I get, when I click on YES, I get the second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAxee.png)

[image: This is the second error that I get]

Where exactly am I missing ?

Comment: Why are you writing to a .xls filename when you are creating an `XSSFWorkbook` (.xlsx)?  Have you tried moving the creation of the `FileOutputStream` before the `for` loop, and the `write`ing of the output file after the `for` loop?  You should only have to write the file once.

Comment: Throws the same error for .xlsx. I did try creating the file before `for` loop. It threw another error when I did that.`org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save:an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@7c81475b`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116189/how-to-fill-in-excel-file-using-java The solution to that exception is in this link.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: What happens if you try upgrading to the latest version then? (either 3.12 beta 1, or a nightly/snapshot build)

Comment: I haven't tried that but considering the answer given by Mrinal Bhattacharjee , same error is being thrown for POI 3.11. Will try with 3.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me with POI 3.11 and MS Office 2013. Although it gives the same warning as yours. However use of SXSSFWorkbook would make it easier.
    
        
        org.apache.poi
        poi
        3.11
    
    
        org.apache.poi
        poi-ooxml
        3.11

[image]

Comment: I am using MS Office 2007. I changed the extension from .xlsx to .xls and again changed it back to .xls. I do not understand how logical would that be, but it did solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some issues fixed. (I did not want to edit your question)

Do you use PIO API by the way? Is the Hello Word application works?

```
int exRows = 2, exCols = 2;
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet xs = wb.createSheet("Sheet");
String input;
FileOutputStream destFile; // declare out of try
try {
        destFile = new FileOutputStream("H:\\Docs\\DestExcelRecord\\DestMedicalRecord.xlsx");
        String[] inputArr = {"Gender", "Age", "Male", "45"};              
        int val =0;
        for(int i =0;i<exRows;i++){
            XSSFRow row = xs.createRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<exCols;j++){
                String str = inputArr[i];                        
                row.createCell(j).setCellValue(str);                        

                val +=val; // is it val += 1;?
            }                   
        }
        wb.write(destFile);
    } finally {
        destFile.close(); // close in finally
    }
```